# How to Set Linux Bonding Interface to Gigabit

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

I have enabled Linux active backup mode bonding.  Each interface is a gigabit interface, but the bond interface seems to end up at 100 Megabit:

```
bonding: bond0: Warning: failed to get speed and duplex from eth1, assumed to be 100Mb/sec and Full.
...
bnx2: eth0 NIC Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex, receive & transmit flow control ON  
... 
bonding: bond0: backup interface eth1 is now up
```

ethtool apparently can't provide info on bond:

```
sudo ethtool bond0
Settings for bond0:
No data available
```

So does this mean I am operating at 100 or 1000 Megabit (My guess is 1000)?  If it is only 100, what options in the ifcfg scripts or the modprobe bonding options do I need to sett to make it 1000?

Comment: I don't think that ethtool would be able to provide information about a virtual interface. You would have to do it on each component interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I am at 1000, someone on the developers mailing list was kind enough to [explain it](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_name=21553.1268075544%40death.nxdomain.ibm.com):

```
...
Later, when the slave device asserts carrier up, bonding will
receive a notifiation, and will update the speed and duplex information
(quietly).
```

Answer (score 1):

Are one of your connections connected to a 100MB switch?

Comment: All gigabit, each individual interface (bnx) negotiates at 1000